# Coloring TextView during a certain time period Android

Tags: java, android, colors, textview

Is there a way to color text in `TextView` or something else in `Android` during certain time period. So it would start off with fully white text and then the `coloring` would move from left to right and fill it up during a certain `duration`. 
So for example if the `duration` would be `10` then the whole line should be color in `10` seconds, but it should also move with the same pace.

Which would look something like this:

[image]

There is a way to do it on `IOS` with `CATextLayer`, but I haven't yet found a way to do it on `Android`.

Comment: You use a shader in an animation that changes the area shaded.  Be aware that animations like this can be ridiculously performance and memory hungry if you aren't careful.

Comment: @GabeSechan is there any way to do it without consuming too much permorfmance because I have a lot of other things going on there

Comment: Preallocating the shaders and just switching between them would cost more memory up front, but save you the time of allocating them constantly which may improve performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just creating a self-defined TextView in last year,here is my class

```
public class AKChangeColorTextView extends TextView {
    public AKChangeColorTextView(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }
    String TAG = "AKChangeColorTextView";
    public AKChangeColorTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs,0);
    }

    RectF mRectF;
    float mX;
    float mY;
    public AKChangeColorTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        mPaint.setXfermode(mode);
        float x = 60;
        float y = 10;
        mY =    0;
        mRectF = new RectF(x, y, x + 50, y + 50);
        mTPaint = getPaint();
        mX = 0;
    }

    Paint mPaint;
    TextPaint mTPaint;
    Bitmap shadowBitmap ;
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Canvas textCanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (shadowBitmap == null) {
            shadowBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getMeasuredWidth(),getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        if (textCanvas == null) {
            textCanvas = new Canvas(shadowBitmap);
        }
        textCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        if (mTPaint == null) {
            mTPaint = getPaint();
        }
        String content  = getText().toString();
        mTPaint.getTextBounds(content,0,content.length(),bounds);
        textCanvas.drawText(content,0,bounds.height(),mTPaint);
        mRectF.set(colorLeft,mY,colorRight,mY+bounds.height()+10);
        textCanvas.drawRect(mRectF,mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(shadowBitmap,0,0,null);
    }
    float colorLeft;
    float colorRight;
    public void setXOffset(float left,float right){
        colorLeft = left;
        colorRight = right;
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

my demo code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "MainActivity"
    lateinit var countDownTimer:CountDownTimer
    var currentOffsetx = 0
    var textWidth = 0
    var isIncrease = true
    lateinit var txt:AKChangeColorTextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        (findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_hello) as AKChangeColorTextView).apply{
            txt = this
        }

        countDownTimer = object:CountDownTimer(300000,200){
            override fun onFinish() {
            }

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                if (textWidth == 0) {
                    textWidth = txt.width
                }
                if (currentOffsetx <= textWidth) {
                    if (isIncrease) {
                        currentOffsetx += 10
                        currentOffsetx = min(currentOffsetx, textWidth)
                    } else {
                        currentOffsetx -= 10
                        currentOffsetx = max(currentOffsetx, 0)
                    }
                }
                if (currentOffsetx == textWidth) {
                    isIncrease = false
                }else if (currentOffsetx == 0) {
                    isIncrease = true
                }
                txt.setXOffset(0f,currentOffsetx.toFloat())
                Log.w(TAG,"check current tick:$millisUntilFinished,offsetx:$currentOffsetx,txtWidth:$textWidth")
            }
        }
        countDownTimer.start()
    }

}
```

my xml layout :

```
<com.example.administrator.myapplication.AKChangeColorTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I Found a Love For Aolphn"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

following is effect

[image]

Comment: Do you have a method to calculate the interval the the `curentOffsetx`?
Lets say I want to fill the sentence in 5000ms, then I would do `CountDownTimer(5000, Interval)` but what is the interval and the `currentOffsetx` (at the moment it is static 10)?

Comment: 5000/width,for example,width is 250,then your interval should be 20

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this optimized, simple, smooth and beautiful: [Vector Animated Drawables (API21+)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable).

There are a lot of tutorials out there (for example [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfiZmzqAMgA) video) that show how you can make beautiful animations. Basically the steps are following:

- create two SVG vector images of your text, one with normal color, the other one with
  colored letters. You can do this easily in Adobe Illustrator for example.
- Import both into [shapeshifter.design](https://shapeshifter.design).
- Create an animation for the second (colored layer) by your liking.
- Copy the resulting xml file into your drawables and you're done!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a text spannable and [Foreground Color Span](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan) and animate one character at a time